# How to apply string.Join to Textbox array?

Tags: c#, textbox

In my C# WinForm application, I have an array of `TextBox` on my form, which looks like:

[MyTextBox[0]] . [MyTextBox[1]] . [MyTextBox[2]] . [MyTextBox[3]] . [MyTextBox[4]]

As you can see, there is a separator "." between each of them. The user will enter 5 different values in those `TextBoxes`, and submit them. When processing, I would like to gather all these 5 `TextBoxes` as one string separated by ".". For example, if the user entered

[34] . [56] . [78] . [90] . [12]

and submitted, I would like to process this as one string: `34.56.78.90.12`.
I was thinking using `string.Join(".", strArray)` would be nice and elegant, but I realized that this is an array of `TextBox`, not an array of string. 
To extract the text portion from the `TextBox`, I have to use `MyTextBox[index].Text` but this obviously won't work with `string.Join(".", strArray)`.

Now, I ended up writing the following code:

```
string[] dataEntered = new string[5];
for(int i=0; dataEntered.Length; i++)
{
    dataEntered[i] = MyTextBox[i].Text;
}
string str = string.Join(".", dataEntered);
```

or, using a string concatenation within a loop too, adding "." each time except after the last value.

But these are both kind of ugly, and I was wondering if there is any better way of achieving this. Can someone give me advice, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `MyTextBox` is the `TextBox[]`? You can use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<string> alltexts = MyTextBox.Select(txt => txt.Text);
string str = string.Join(".", alltexts);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is way more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Use linq:

```
string str = string.Join(".", MyTextBox.Select(t => t.Text));
```

Comment: Thank you! I have always avoided Linq. Maybe it is about time I started learning.

Comment: Once you get the hang of it its very useful; saves many lines of code.